# PFUser Subclassing: Local-Only (non-db) User Properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've subclassed PFUser, adding several properties that translate directly to database storage, such as gender and birthDate:

```
// Define property
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSDate *birthDate; 

// and later on...

// Instruct compiler to leave setter/getter up to us (Parse)
@dynamic signUpComplete, birthDate, paypalEmail, gender;
```

These properties work fine, and are committed to storage reliably.

My question: how can I add regular 'private' properties that do ***not* get stored in the database**?

My initial thought was to simply define regular properties as usual, and call @syntheize on them rather than @dynamic. This *seems* to work fine, but Parse did dump a message to console about PFUser Key Not Found.

Will @synthensize prevent local-only properties from being written to db, reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would override the `saveInBackground:` method in your PFUser subclass in order to accomplish your goal. Something like this:

Header file:

```
@interface PFUserSubclass : PFUser

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customPropertyToSave;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customPropertyToIgnore;

- (void)saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
@implementation PFUserSubclass

@synthesize customPropertyToSave;
@synthesize customPropertyToIgnore;

- (void)saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block {
    PFUser *userToSave = [PFUser currentUser];
    [userToSave setObject:self.customPropertyToSave forKey:@"customProperty"];
    [userToSave saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        block(succeeded, error);
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Essentially, manually saving the properties that I want to save and discarding the rest. Sounds like a possible solution. I'm curious though - does saveInBackground save all properties, or just @dynamic ones?

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure, though it should be easy enough to test to find out. However - I don't really think that going that route would be obvious to another developer (or your future self) which might lead to bugs.

Comment: That seems to be the behavior. Anyway, I'm all for verbosity - marking this as answered until I get to see the actual code for saveInBackground.